# Fragment's method onResume stops being called when Activity's method recreate() is called

Tags: android-fragments, recreate

When i call recreate() for activity, my fragments do not call method onResume(), but they stil call onCreate() and onCreateView(). If I block my device and then unblock it, onResume() fires. Please explain to me why fragment's method onResume() stops working after recreate() for activity is called and what should i do?

Comment: Hey did you find a solution? I am also stuck with this issue.

Comment: @q126y, it seems to me it is a bug. You are supposed to finish() and startActivity() manually